# Vue3 Router - Params always empty

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

Currently I'm creating a navigation guard to an application and to keep the code simple, I'll  mock some data.

```js
export function useNavigationGuard() {
    return async (to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized, next: NavigationGuardNext) => {

        const canNavigate = false;
        if (!canNavigate) {
            console.log('forbidden');
            return next({ name: '/forbidden', params: { to: to.fullPath } });
        }
        return next();
    };
}
```

Then I'm receiving it in my forbidden page

```html
<template>
    <span class="text-h6">You are not allowed to acces this resource</span>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface IForbiddenViewComponentProperties {
    to?: string;
}
const componentProperties: IForbiddenViewComponentProperties = withDefaults(
    defineProps<IForbiddenViewComponentProperties>(),
    {},
);
</script>
```

This is the forbidden route:

```js
{
    path: '/forbidden',
    name: '/forbidden',
    props: useRouteParamsAsProperties,
    component: () => import('@views/forbidden/index.vue'),
},
```

and here is the useRouteParamsAsProperties composable

```js
import { RouteLocationNormalized } from 'vue-router';

export function useRouteParamsAsProperties(route: RouteLocationNormalized) {
    const { params } = route;
    return {
        ...params,
    };
}
export default useRouteParamsAsProperties;
```

But when I try to check **to** property in my component property, it's always undefined.

Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple mistake

In order to pass the parameter according to [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html)

I needed to add the parameter in the route path like:

```js
{
    path: '/forbidden/:to',
    name: '/forbidden',
    props: useRouteParamsAsProperties,
    component: () => import('@views/forbidden/index.vue'),
},
```